# How can I just one header file based on some condition?

Tags: c, header, modular-design

I have two header files:a.h and b.h. I want to use only one of them, based on some condition. How can I do this?

Here some code:

main.c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"a.h"
#include"b.h"
main() {
    test();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

a.h:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
#include<stdio.h>
void test();
#endif
```

a.c:

```
#include "a.h"
void test() {
    printf("Got tested from a.\n");
}
```

b.h:

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H
#include<stdio.h>
void test();
#endif
```

b.c:

```
#include "b.h"
void test() {
    printf("Got tested from b.\n");
}
```

As I've said before,I only want to use one of them.How can I do this?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "condition" and "use a header file". [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) might be enlightening, it shows how to include contents of the header file on the condition that they have not been already included. You should explain what condition you want to use.

Comment: @hyde Well,that's not kind of what I'm looking for.Maybe I wasn't clear enough,but first of all those two header files are independent.And regarding the condition,I don't have a specific condition in mind.It's just up to me to think about one,because that's what my assignment tells me to do.

Comment: Indeed. You should show some example code. If I interpret what you say correctly, then no, you can't do that. Or, maybe, your question doesn't actually have anything to do with header files? Hard to say without code.

Comment: @hyde I'll edit my question as soon as possible in order to add some code which will most likely more clarity to you.

Comment: The code you show does not compile, as I am sure you know. What are you trying to achieve? Here `test` is a global symbol and it can't have multiple different definitions. How to work around this depends on what actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @hyde I know it doesn't compile."What are you trying to achieve?"Like I said,I want to be able to use the function ```test``` from just one header,despite being included two headers that contain this function.

Comment: Also note that include files are just text, which is essentially copy-pasted to .c file when building. Since these .h files have same relevant content, you could just have one *ab.h* and include that.

Comment: @hyde One more thing,I edited ```test1()``` and ```test2()``` to ```test()``` to make it clear what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Well, you can't link with both a.c and b.c, as they have same symbol `test` with conflicting definition. So you need to make this choice at build time. And you really want just 1 header file.

Comment: Or, you could build a dynamic library and load it dynamically at runtime from the file you want (.so on unix,  .dll on Windows). IOW use a plugin system.

Comment: And how can I make this choice at build time?

Comment: What build system do you use?

Comment: By build system do you mean IDE or another specific tool?

Comment: What ever you use to build this. I mean, this problem is not something which is covered by the C standard (other than, you can not do this). So solution must come from somewhere else. Oh, one more option, which would be pure C: use preprosessor macro to rename the function in a.c and b.c (say, to `test_a` and `test_b` before they are compiled, and then another function or macro with name `test` which selects which one to call. It all depends on *what is the purpose of all this*.

Comment: 'what is the purpose of all this?`.I don't really know to be honest with you.Like I said,it's an assignment that I got from my OOP course(yes I know,it seems kinda weird to get introduced first with C modular programming).I guess it's to test overloaded functions?Anyway,regarding what I use to build is Visual Studio 2019.That's all I can say.